# Restore keyboard after rotation in Jetpack Compose

Tags: material-design, android-jetpack-compose

I have a `TextField` on one of my app screens. When I rotate my device the text field retains the value, but not the soft keyboard focus.

How could I keep the focus and prevent the keyboard from disappearing?

Here is a simplified version of the composable for the screen:

```
@Composable
fun LoginScreen(
    uiState: LoginUiState,
) {
    MyTheme {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .verticalScroll(scrollableState)
                .imePadding(),
        ) {
            Column(
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                TextField(
                    value = uiState.email,
                    enabled = !uiState.isLoggingIn
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The UI state comes from the model.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `rememberSaveable` to store wither the `TextField` was focused previously.

```
  val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
    var hasFocus by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }
    
    TextField(
        value = ...,
        onValueChange = { ... },
        modifier = Modifier.focusRequester(focusRequester).onFocusChanged {
            hasFocus = it.hasFocus
        }
    )
    LaunchedEffect(hasFocus){
        if(hasFocus) {
            focusRequester.requestFocus()
        }
    }
```

Comment: No need to use the saveable with the focusRequestor. It's ok if it is re-created. You only need that value with the value of the `TextField`. Also, no need to pass `hasFocus` as the key of the side-effect. It will cause unnecessary code calls when the focus changes, while we just want the focus to be gained back once the configuration changes.

Comment: We need to launch the side effect only once and yes, it will be called on focus changed. LaunchedEffect will prevent requesting focus again and again if the the recomposition is triggered by something else.

Comment: No sir, the focus will not be requested again and again on recompositions even if you do not use the side-effect. That's what `remember` is for, isn't it?

Comment: Thank you. Your answer and the addition from @MARSK gave me enough information to implement the desired behaviour. At the same time, the code as you provided is not enough. In my tests, `hasFocus` gets reset right before the rotation. And after rotation the `LaunchedEffect` block does nothing. I had to implement a more complex way to detect what actually have focus and save this information in my model.

Comment: @Bobrovsky Can you share what you came up with in the end, please?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the a state-preserver like a ViewModel here, I suppose. You could either store the value in a `rememberSaveable` block, as Nikola suggests, or you could simply put a simple Boolean where you put the uiState parameter. There's no need to use `MutableState<T>` this way. Also, no side-effects are required. Just create a parameter.

```
@Composable
fun MyFiled(
 loginState: ... , 
 isFocused: Boolean
){
 if (isFocused)
   focusRequestor.requestFocus()
 ... 
}
```

Just put a simple condition, and it'll do.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is related to this [issue about TextField losing focus on configuration change](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/192776771)
.

A possible temporary solution is to save focus boolean changes from modifier `onFocusChanged` into a variable using `rememberSaveable`, then use a `LaunchedEffect` to restore focus to the `TextField` when it enters the composition.

```
val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
var isFocused by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }

LaunchedEffect(true) {
    if (isFocused) {
        focusRequester.requestFocus()
    }
}

var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { text = it },
    modifier = Modifier
        .focusRequester(focusRequester)
        .onFocusChanged {
            isFocused = it.isFocused
        }
)
```

However, this solution doesn't seem to work because when the `TextField` enters the composition, `onFocusChanged` is called right away and updates `isFocused` to `false` before the `LaunchedEffect` has a chance to process the previous value.

Therefore, an additional variable can be used to store the value from `isFocused` before it's updated. Below I name it `wasFocused`:

```
val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
var isFocused by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }
val wasFocused = remember { isFocused }

LaunchedEffect(true) {
    if (wasFocused) {
        focusRequester.requestFocus()
    }
}

var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { text = it },
    modifier = Modifier
        .focusRequester(focusRequester)
        .onFocusChanged {
            isFocused = it.isFocused
        }
)
```

This works in my android emulator after rotating the device. Let me know if it doesn't restore the focus for you on your device.

(I should mention that this solution is for a simple case. An issue may arise when used in a more complex case, such as many `TextField`s in something like a `LazyColumn`. I do have such a case, and use this as part of my solution).

Answer (score 0):

You can also set this in your activity manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:configChanges="density|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|layoutDirection|locale|mcc|mnc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|touchscreen|uiMode"
```

In the Compose world, you don't need to destroy your activity. On configuration change, you will see that the composables recompose. This above fixes the issue with retaining the keyboard state.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code which use focusRequester to change the focus after orientation:

```
val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
var isFirstComposition by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(true) }
TextField(
    value = ...,
    onValueChange = { ... },
    modifier = Modifier.focusRequester(focusRequester)
)
LaunchedEffect(focusRequester) {
    if (!isFirstComposition) {
        focusRequester.requestFocus()
    }
    isFirstComposition = false
}
```